# Unity3D execute code before the game closes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shutdown, application-shutdown

**Is it possible to run code before the Unity player is closed** (by closed, we mean all ways of closing the program, either by Alt+F4, pressing the X button on the window corners, closed from within the game, etc.)? If yes, **how**?

Comment: If it were WinForms, you'd want to subscribe to the `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event. Not sure if Unity3D supports that, though...

Comment: Is it [OnApplicationQuit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) ?

Comment: Awesome. That seems so trivial I feel so dumb. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`OnApplicationQuit()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) method.